# SQL Server script loops through each record and updates it

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

How can I write an equivalent SQL script in T-SQL?

I've written this code in MS Access to edit records - how can I do the same thing in SQL Server?

For each combination of `J_CaseNum` and `J_Index J_PersonIndex` needs to be incremented. There can be anywhere from 1 to 50 person for a given combination.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String

sql = "Select J_CaseNum, J_Index, J_VehicleIndex, J_PersonIndex, J_CaseNo, J_PersonID, Ind_Last_NM  from dbo_DCIPS Order By J_CaseNum, J_Index, Ind_Last_NM"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

rs.MoveLast
cnt = rs.RecordCount
rs.MoveFirst
i = 0

SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "_", cnt

While Not rs.EOF
    If i = 0 Then
        rs.Edit
        rs!J_PersonIndex = "01"
        rs!J_CaseNo = rs!J_CaseNum & rs!J_Index
        rs!J_PersonID = rs!J_CaseNo & rs!J_VehicleIndex & rs!J_PersonIndex
        rs.Update
        j = 1
        i = 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Else
        If (rs1!J_CaseNum = rs!J_CaseNum) And (rs1!J_Index = rs!J_Index) Then
            j = j + 1
            s = j
            rs.Edit
            rs!J_PersonIndex = Right("00" + s, 2)
            rs!J_CaseNo = rs!J_CaseNum & rs!J_Index
            rs!J_PersonID = rs!J_CaseNo & rs!J_VehicleIndex & rs!J_PersonIndex
            rs.Update
            rs.MoveNext
            rs1.MoveNext
        Else
            j = 1
            s = j
            rs.Edit
            rs!J_PersonIndex = Right("00" + s, 2)
            rs!J_CaseNo = rs!J_CaseNum & rs!J_Index
            rs!J_PersonID = rs!J_CaseNo & rs!J_VehicleIndex & rs!J_PersonIndex
            rs.Update
            rs.MoveNext
            rs1.MoveNext
        End If
    End If

    i = i + 1
    SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, i

    If (i Mod 1000) = 0 Then Stop
Wend
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question / what are you having trouble with? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Can a combination be repeated or are they unique? Do you want the J_PersonIndex to be a static number or is it generated every time this is queried?

Comment: the J_PersonIndex will be a static value.  This is a one time update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so you want a counter in each group of case/index/person. I would do something like this to get a unique person id.

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY caseNum,[index] order by [index])      
    AS personId , caseNum, [index], personName FROM table
```

And then you can use this dataset to insert into a new table or update existing table from this query (which is a modified command)

Comment: I am new to writing SQL code and never heard of cross join. It's a single table that I'm working with.  The reason why I used two recordset is to test when changes happens in the two columns so i can reset the personIndex back to 01 for the new group.  
for example:
CaseNum  Index      Name   PersonID
10001         001  Smith    01
10001         001        Pat        02
10001         002        allice     01
10002         001        smith     01

Comment: @user7355774 
ok so you want a counter in each group of case/index/person.  

I would do something like this to get a unique person id.

`code
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (partition BY caseNum,[index] order by [index]) AS personId ,
                caseNum, [index],  personName
      FROM table
 `

And then you can use this dataset to insert into a new table or update existing table from this query (which is another step)